# FTDI libMPSSE.dll I2C_DeviceRead() always returns 0xFF

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, i2c, ftdi

I make import of the FTDI Chip libMPSSE.dll and use it in I2C mode. My test device is sensor BMP280. I try read it's ID register, that contains 0x58 value. The problem is method *I2C_DeviceRead()* always returns 0xFF, although I see with the logic analyzer that sensor answers correctly:
[image: Logic analyzer shows correct answer of the sensor]

Original declarations of the methods are:

```
FT_STATUS I2C_DeviceRead(FT_HANDLE handle, uint32 deviceAddress, uint32 sizeToTransfer, uint8 *buffer, uint32 *sizeTransferred, uint32 options)
FT_STATUS I2C_DeviceWrite(FT_HANDLE handle, uint32 deviceAddress, uint32 sizeToTransfer, uint8 *buffer, uint32 *sizeTransferred, uint32 options)
```

I import this methods like this:

```
<DllImport(DLL_MPSSE_PATH, SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Private Shared Function I2C_DeviceRead(ByVal handle As Integer, ByVal deviceAddress As Integer, ByVal sizeToTransfer As Integer, ByVal buffer As Byte(), ByRef sizeTransfered As Integer, ByVal options As I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport(DLL_MPSSE_PATH, SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Private Shared Function I2C_DeviceWrite(ByVal handle As Integer, ByVal deviceAddress As Integer, ByVal sizeToTransfer As Integer, ByVal buffer As Byte(), ByRef sizeTransfered As Integer, ByVal options As I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS) As Integer
End Function
```

I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS is the Enum with control bits mask.
And further call it (pseudo-code) according to sensor datasheet. First, write register address:

```
Dim sensorAddr as Integer = &H77
Dim idRegister as Byte() = {&HD0}
Dim options as Integer = &H13 'I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_START_BIT | I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_STOP_BIT | I2C_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_FAST_TRANSFER_BYTES
Dim transferred as Integer = 0
I2C_DeviceWrite(myhandle, sensorAddr, 1, idRegister, transferred, options)
```

Then read content of the sensor's register:

```
Dim readLen as Integer = 1
Dim readBuf(readLen-1) as Byte
I2C_DeviceRead(myhandle, sensorAddr, readLen, readBuf, transferred, options)
```

If readLen is, e.g. 4, so readBuf() contains four 0xFF, although sensor writes to data line (SDA on the picture) other values:
[image: Each requested byte is 0xFF]

What is the problem with my code? Why I can write correctly, but reading is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Code looks good, [check this](https://www.i2c-bus.org/i2c-primer/analysing-obscure-problems/data-bytes-from-slave-are-0xff/).

Comment: @HansPassant nope, it's not a reason, unfortunately... Time diagrams are shows it. But thank you for the link, any way.

Comment: I've checked this issue with unmanaged QT, and the result is same.  So, the problem is caused not by marshalling and p/invoke, as I see.